# How add Item to array

Tags: arrays, typescript, redux

```
export type CartState = {
    id:string;
    name:string;
    price:number;
    src:string
}

export type CorzinaState = {
    id:string;
    name:string;
    price:number;
    src:string
}

 export type CartArray = {
    Carts:CartState[],
     Corzina:CorzinaState[]
}


const initialState:CartArray = {
        Carts:[{
            id:'0',
            name:'Крем для тела Japanies Camelia',
            price : 500,
            src:"https://www.thebodyshop.ru/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/240x240/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/4/1/41334_01.jpg"
        },
            {
                id:'1',
                name:'Защитный крем для рук \"Конопляное масло \"',
                price : 2500,
                src:"https://www.thebodyshop.ru/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/240x240/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/8/9/89356.jpg"
            },
            {
                id:'2',
                name:'Массажер-роллер для лица Oils of Life™ ',
                price : 5000,
                src:"https://www.thebodyshop.ru/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/240x240/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/b/a/back1.d-31627.jpg"
            }
        ],
    Corzina:[]
}

const reducer = (state:CartArray = initialState ,action:any):CartArray =>{
    switch (action.type){
        case "ADD_ITEM":

            const containsId  = state.Corzina?.some(item=>item.id===action.payload.id)
            const FindedItem = state.Carts.filter(item=>item.id===action.payload)

            if(!containsId){
                return {
                    ...state,...Corzina,FindedItem
                }
            }

            return {
                ...state
            }


        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

How add FindedItem to Corzina?

I have that error

> TS2322: Type '{ FindedItem: CartState[];
> Carts: CartState[]; Corzina: CorzinaState[]; }' is not assignable to type 'CartArray'.   
> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'FindedItem' does not exist in type 'CartArray'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `.filter()` which returns an `array` you can use `.find()` which returns the matching item or `undefined` if none found.

Ideally you would design this so that you don't have data duplicated in multiple places.  The basket might just have the `id` and `quantity` of the added items.

But for now you are asking to include the whole item, so here's how you do that:

```
const containsId = state.Corzina?.some(item => item.id === action.payload.id)
const FindedItem = state.Carts.find(item => item.id === action.payload)

if (!containsId && FindedItem) {
  return {
    ...state,
    Corzina: [...state.Corzina, FindedItem]
  }
}
```